# Removing elements from an array such that the sum becomes less than or equal to a particular value. (Not subarray)

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization

I came across a practice problem wherein I am given with an array and I want to remove certain elements from it so that the sum becomes less than a given value but also the sum should be near to the given value.

Let the value be 17 and the array given be [2, 5, 6 , 8] then I can remove element 2nd such that the new array becomes [2, 6, 8] and the obtained sum is 16. Assume array to be in increasing order.

My attempt:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef long long int ll;


int main(){
    ll a,b;
    cin>>a>>b;
    vector<ll> v;
    map<ll,vector<ll>> mp;
    ll sum=0;
    for(ll i=0;i<b;i++){
        ll x;
        cin>>x;
        v.push_back(x);
        mp[x].push_back(i);
        sum+=x;
    }
    for(auto x:v) cout << x << " ";
    cout << endl;
  //  cout << sum << endl;
    if(sum<=a){
        cout << b << endl;
        for(ll i=0;i<b;i++){
            cout << i << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
   else{
       // sort(v.begin(),v.end());
        vector<ll> ind;

            cout << "sum:" << sum<< endl;
            for(auto i=v.begin();i!=v.end();++i){
               cout << "i val:" << (*i) << endl;
                sum = sum - (*i);
                ind.push_back(*mp[*i].begin());
                mp[*i].erase(mp[*i].begin());
                v.erase(i-1,i);
                for(auto x:v) cout << x << " ";
                cout << endl;
                if(sum>a) continue;
                else break;
            }
        cout << sum << endl;

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not even asking for code, I'm just asking for logic.

Comment: Does it matter how many elements are in the result? If you array is `{1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2}` and your target sum is '4', is `{1, 1, 1, 1}` equally as a valid as `{2, 2}`? Is there a preference for sign when measuring distance to goal? If your array is `{1, 3}` and your target is `2`, is `{1}` equally as valid as `{3}`?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165519/where-should-i-post-questions-about-algorithms-stack-overflow-or-software-engin

Comment: @John The resulting array size doesn't matter in this case, it's just the problem I'm getting in optimizing the algo.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I've added "my attempt" which you were asking, would be glad if you could help.

Comment: What exactly is your goal here? Is it to learn C++, or learn a particular algorithm?

Comment: Now we need to decipher those horrible macros and typedefs and replace that `bits.` header with a standard one.

Comment: I've clearly stated my goal in the question title, which is learning algorithm ofcourse.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That's why I didn't included code at first, but Sam asked for it, so here it is! XD

Comment: Sounds like your goal is to figure out the correct algorithm. Someone else will need to help you. My particular interests are oriented towards technical, practical aspects of C++, and I have very little interests in non-practical puzzles, that are typically found on line quiz/hacker sites that are of little practical worth.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Okay, very cool.

Comment: Add all numbers, then use binary search to find the number(s) to remove to get to the goal amount.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Can you please write a proper answer regarding your approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure it's ordered. In a loop, starting with the largest number in the array, subtract it from the sum. Compare to the target value, if sum still greater then remove and go back to start of loop, if not then store the absolute value (DIF) in a variable and restart the loop. Now your loop should look at the next largest number in the array and subtract from sum. Assuming we have a value for DIF, compare the absolute value of the current comparison to DIF. If DIF is closer then remove the previous number, exit the loop, and you are done. Otherwise you'll continue until you find the best result.